# How to convert a JavaScript array to a PHP array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am new to PHP and would like to bring the following array to a database.

I think, the best way is to convert it first to a PHP array.

```
var bildInfo = new Array();

bildInfo[0]  = "dummy";

bildInfo[1] = new Array();
bildInfo[1][0] = "Karaffen";
bildInfo[1][1] = "Öl auf Leinwand";
bildInfo[1][2] = "83 x 120 cm";
bildInfo[1][3] = " - ";
bildInfo[1][4] = "1";

bildInfo[2] = new Array();
bildInfo[2][0] = "Santé";
bildInfo[2][1] = "Öl auf Leinwand";
bildInfo[2][2] = "80 x 100 cm";
bildInfo[2][3] = " - ";
bildInfo[2][4] = "1";

bildInfo[3] = new Array();
bildInfo[3][0] = "Landleben I";
bildInfo[3][1] = "Öl auf Leinwand";
bildInfo[3][2] = "70 x 100 cm";
bildInfo[3][3] = " - ";
bildInfo[3][4] = "1";

bildInfo[4] = new Array();
bildInfo[4][0] = "Landleben II";
bildInfo[4][1] = "Öl auf Leinwand";
bildInfo[4][2] = "70 x 100 cm";
bildInfo[4][3] = " - ";
bildInfo[4][4] = "1";
```

and 700 more ...

Because of the quantity I am asking for some hints to find the best way to do that.

The array is in a JS/TXT-file, so my first idea was a simple search-replace like `bildInfo` to `$bildInfo`, but I do not know how to deal the "new Array()".

Comment: How to you access/generate your JS array ?

Comment: Looks to me like you are storing the data in a nefarious way. JavaScript has a key, value data structure known as an object, akin to PHPs array structure you are thinking about.

Comment: I would use JSON on both sides - so: 1. create JSON in JS 2. stringify and post to PHP 3. get JSON in PHP, validate it and use it in loops with (My)SQL prepared sentences...

Comment: Exactly, export your JS output with JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your Javascript array as JSON object then send it with an Ajax call to a Php web page.

Javascript client side :

```
 var json = $.stringify(bildInfo);
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api.php",
            data: {data : json},
            timeout: 6000,
            error: function(a, b) {
                if ("timeout" == b) $("#err-timedout").slideDown("slow"); else {
                    $("#err-state").slideDown("slow");
                    $("#err-state").html("An error occurred: " + b);
                }
            },
            success: function(a) {
            }
 });
```

Php server side :

```
  $json_object = json_decode($_POST['data']);
  // play with your json object with Php.
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to convert to a php array is using JSON.

First in javascript you would make it a json string like this:

**JavaScript**

```
var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(my_javascript_array);
```

Now you can send that through ajax or how ever you want to give it to php, then in php you would decode it.

**PHP**

```
$myphpArray = json_decode($json_string);
var_dump($myphpArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think more importantly is to know how to pass any data type to backend... here's high level:

1) Pass the frontend JS val to backend (here you can do it asynchronously with AJAX)- here I'm using a jQuery wrapper $.get to do it:

```
var yourJSON = $.stringify(bildInfo); //stringify array into JSON so it can be used in DB:

    $.get("./path/to/php/file.php", {
        "_variable"  : yourJSON //bind val within the object you're passing in
        },
        function (result) { 
            //do something with the result when it's returned if needed
        }
    );
```

2) Get the frontend JS val passed in to backend with `$_GET`:

```
$receivedVal = $_GET['_variable'];
```

Although you may want to check if it's set first with `isset()`... (if it's set, set it to value, if not, set it to default to prevent nulls):

```
$receivedVal = (isset($_GET['_variable']) ? ($_GET['_variable']) : 0);

$phpArray = json_decode($receivedVal); //decode it and use it how you want
```

3) Query the DB:

```
    $qry = 'INSERT INTO yourTable (column_a)
            VALUES ("' . $phpArray . '")';  

    $result = $mysqli->query($qry) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); //runs fine, or outputs error
```